# How to return value to index page from an included script page?

Tags: php, function, include

index.php

```
<?php   
$surl = "http://myweb.com/myfolder/include.php";
$me_arr  = array(array('method'=>'x', 'param1'=> 5, 'param2'=> 3),array('method'=>'y', 'param1'=> 2, 'param2'=> 2));
$json_data = json_encode($me_arr);
$strResult = include($surl."?me_Name=".$json_data);

echo $strResult; 
?>
```

include.php

```
<?php
$method = (isset($_GET['me_Name']))?json_decode($_GET['me_Name'],true):'array()';

if(isset($method))
{
foreach (($method) as $extMethod)
{
$func = $extMethod['method'];
$param1 = $extMethod['param1'];
$param2 = $extMethod['param2'];

$func($param1,$param2,$z);
}
}   
function x($x, $y, $z)
{
$z=$y+$x;
echo $z;
}         
function y($x, $y, $z)
{
$z=$y+$x;
echo $z;
}
?>
```

This code works perfectly fine but I want to return the value of `z` to **index.php** not echo in **include page** . But `return $z;` doesn't work here, just give me the output **1** in **index.php**. Any way to solve this problem ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is calling your return function

Comment: You can only use `return` to pass data from an include file back to the including script, if you actually operate on the file system level. You’re not making your include via the file system here, you are including via an HTTP URL - and that is a completely different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In you index.php page after inclusion you can use $z variable as like

```
<?php   
$surl = "http://myweb.com/myfolder/include.php";
$me_arr  = array(array('method'=>'x', 'param1'=> 5, 'param2'=> 3),array('method'=>'y', 'param1'=> 2, 'param2'=> 2));
$json_data = json_encode($methodarr);
$strResult = include($surl."?me_Name=".$json_data);

echo $z; // Using variable from include page
?>
```

Comment: No it doesnt make any sense

Comment: @ssslll You wanted to return a value from your include page to use it in your main page. But it serves your need. May be I don't know what actually you want

Comment: I want to return the z value from include page and echo it in index page

Comment: @ssslll it automatically returned without return syntax. First you have to understand how include works. If you define a function in the include page, then there you can use return.